# C# WPF Linq to SQL Databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, data-binding

i have generated a Linq to Sql class which looks like this.

[image]

so i have 3 querys which gets my data.

```
private IQueryable<Gesellschaft> loadedGesellschaft;
private IQueryable<Anschrift> loadedGesellschaftAnschrift;
private IQueryable<Email> loadedGesellschaftEmail;
private lgDataContext completeGesellschaft;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        completeGesellschaft = new lgDatacontext();
        loadedGesellschaft = completeGesellschaft.Gesellschaft.Where(gid => gid.GID == 2);
        loadedGesellschaftAnschrift = completeGesellschaft.Anschrift.Where(FK_GID => FK_GID.FK_GesellschaftId == loadedGesellschaft.First().GID);
        loadedGesellschaftEmail = completeGesellschaft.Email.Where(FK_GID => FK_GID.FK_AnschriftId == loadedHauptanschrift.First().idAnschrift);
    }
```

After this i want to put these 3 on my page. The Result is something like this there one Office(loadedGesellschaft) and that has maybe more than one Adress(loadedGesellschaftAnschrift) and has maybe more than one Email(loadedGesellschaftEmail)
so i have on my window some textboxes which contain the fields from loadedGesellschaft and Adresses and Emails are stored in comboboxes.

do i always have to bind the itemsource of one Control e.g.

`<ComboBox   Name="CBox_GDEmail" />`

```
CBoxGDEmail.Itemsource = loadedGesellschaftEmail;
```

or is there an possibility to put all three objects together to the datacontext of the window ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create three classes:  `Gesellschaft`, `Anschrift`, and `Email`.  These classes are view models; they expose any property whose value you want to see in the view.  Make `Gesellschaft` expose an `Anschriften` property of type `IEnumerable<Anschrift>`, and `Anschrift` expose an `Emails` property of type `IEnumerable<Email>`.  (I'm just sort of guessing at what the plural of Anschrift is; pretty much all of my knowledge of German comes from board games.)

In your XAML, create three `DataTemplate`s, e.g.:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Gesellschaft}">
   <WrapPanel>
      <Label>Name</Label>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Gesellschaftname}"/>
      ...
      <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Anschriften}"/>
  </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Obviously you'll want to use a saner layout than sticking a bunch of controls in a `WrapPanel`; this is just a proof of concept.  The `DataTemplate` for `Anschrift` should similarly have a `ListBox` whose `ItemsSource` is bound to `Emails`.

Once you've done this, all you need in your XAML is to set the `DataContext` of a `ContentPresenter` to an instance of `Gesellschaft`.  It will be rendered using the `DataTemplate` that you've defined for that type.  Its `ListBox` will contain an item for each `Anschrift`, rendered using that type's template.  U.s.w.

Congratulations, you're now using the MVVM pattern just like all the cool kids.  There's a lot more to learn about than just this, but this is a good start.

Comment: i`m trying to transform this now to my needs. A Question im trying to add INotifyPropertyChanged to my new ViewModel Class should i take instead of IEnumerable<Email> e.g. an ObservableCollection<Email> ? (Anschriften is the right plural of Anschrift ;))

Comment: Yes, if you're going to be adding or removing entries from the collection, you'll want it to be an ObservableCollection<Email>.

Comment: Hi another time, how do you implement the VW if it has settings, umm like i have a datagrid and i want to specify the columns the it would display. Say i want to specify which columns are displayed from the database in the grid. So im a little bit stuck in that. My VM Class should then consist of lists of all columns which are possible ? And how do i tell my WPF apllication to only Display that Columns which i want to be displayed. I hope that i announced that probably.

Comment: There are many different ways of handling this, and the appropriate one really depends on your specific requirements.  I think you should probably post this as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Combine your three objects together in a [ViewModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) object.